# Make NSWindow truly the highest level (above mouse, above mission control/expose)

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nswindow

I was wondering if it is possible to make my NSWindow show above absolutely everything.  I current set the window level to CGShieldingWindowLevel using the code...

```
[self setLevel:CGShieldingWindowLevel()];
```

...and this does a great job for the most part, but it isn't quite enough.  The window is not drawn when mission control or expose is active,  and it is drawn below the mouse.  I was wondering if it was possible to crearte a truly "top level" which would be drawn above all these elements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Considering the mouse is one of the most fundamental aspects of any modern computer, I'd be surprised if you could... But since the NSWindow levels are integers... Have you tried adding one?

Comment: Good idea, but sadly, still a no-go.  Just for the hell of it I checked what the actually integer values of these constants were.  Turns out NSScreenSaverWindowLevel = 1000, and CGShieldingWindowLevel() = a whopping 2147483629.  I tried adding one to both with no avail, as well as multiplying CGShieldingWindowLevel() by two, which left me with no window at all.  Any other ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Truly the highest level is above the monitor's surface.

Comment: Very funny, Davyd :P  Sadly I think something like that will be hard to distribute on the Mac App Store...

Comment: What is the greater goal you're trying to accomplish? As far as I know there are no _official_ APIs to do this.

Comment: I made a multi-monitor screen dimming app ([ScreenDimmer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screendimmer/id562058942?mt=12)) and I want it to display ALL the time.  Currently it disappears when expose or mission control is brought up.  This is, of course, "correct" behavior seeing as how it is an NSWindow.  I was wondering if there was any way around this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In regards to your question about Expose, you probably just haven't set your collection behavior correctly. Make a subclass of `NSWindow`, and somewhere in your initialization do something along the following:

```
self.collectionBehavior = (NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorIgnoresCycle);
```

If you want your window on all spaces (which you probably do) don't forget to also add `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces`.

In terms of your question about the mouse, unfortunately I do not think there's a way to draw above it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Although this only accomplishes 1/3 of what I needed, I am beginning to realize the other 2/3rds aren't exactly possible...

Comment: @AtlasWegman: The other part was the mouse, and what else? For all intents and purposes I believe drawing above the mouse is impossible. I just checked another utility like yours, Shady, and it does not draw above the mouse.

Comment: The other big one (which I am beggining to realize is impossible with the stock NSWindow class) is drawing over Mission Control.  Any ideas on how something like this could be accomplished?  Thanks!

Comment: @AtlasWegman: There is a good chance it is possible, but I do not know of any way to do that offhand. If there is a way, it's probably going to be through a private API which wouldn't be safe for App Store submission.

Comment: Thanks for all the information!  I am pretty happy with the app as it stands currently :)